# iOS framework is not able to be updated after the initial archiving

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6, ios-frameworks

I am creating an iOS framework to be used in another app. I roughly followed [this tutorial](https://kodmunki.wordpress.com/2015/03/04/cocoa-touch-frameworks-for-ios8-remix/) in order to get up and going.

Everything worked fine initially. I archived the project which was as simple as the following:

**E.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

FOUNDATION_EXPORT double EVersionNumber;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char EVersionString[];

@interface E : NSObject

+ (void)showAlert;

@end
```

**E.m**

```
#import "E.h"

@implementation E

+ (void)showAlert {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello There!"
                                                    message:@""
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cool"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}    

@end
```

I included the archived output of the Debug and Release directories into my app, and added the reference to the `.framework` file via the Embedded Binary section of the app's build settings.

I ran the app with this main bit:

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "E.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [E showAlert];
}

@end
```

Everything works perfectly here.

However, the weirdness started when I tried to add a method to the framework's code. I updated all the versioning, cleaned, archived the new version of the framework, wiped the all the old framework info out of the app where it was included, and then added the new version of the framework to the app.

Here are the updated framework files:

**E.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

FOUNDATION_EXPORT double EVersionNumber;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char EVersionString[];

@interface E : NSObject

+ (void)showAlert;
+ (void)showNewAlert;

@end
```

**E.m**

```
#import "E.h"

@implementation E

+ (void)showAlert {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello There!"
                                                    message:@""
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cool"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}    

+ (void)showNewAlert {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Method!"
                                                    message:@"Does this work??"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cool"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

@end
```

I ran the app with this new code:

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "E.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [E showNewAlert];
}

@end
```

The app builds successfully, but I get this when I run it:

```
+[E showNewAlert]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10ef57188
```

Comment: Did you add the new method to your .h as well?

Comment: Yep, just double checked.

Comment: Can you post the full updated classes to compare the originals to the new? Also can you temporarily revert to the old and verify that it still works that way?

Comment: Done. And I checked calling the old method, and it still works perfectly.

Comment: That's super weird. Try cleaning?

Comment: Also what does the resulting header that's contained in the included framework look like?

Comment: @remus Deleted Derived Data, cleaned, then ran. No dice :(

Comment: @Captnwalker1 it looks like the *second* listing of the contents of E.h above

Comment: Try to import the class like this `#import <FrameworkName/E.h>` and have you added your framework that it needs to be added?

Comment: I've added my framework as described above, yes. Tried that style of import and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Why is E a subclass of NSObject and not a subclass of UIViewController?

Comment: Not entirely sure. Should that matter? I just needed the class method(s) from E, and it seemed to be working just fine at the beginning.